# Creating lexicographicaly sorted pairs in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, cbind, lexicographic

How can I efficiently bind two keyed columns into a single column of **pairs** that will preserve the lexicographic order of the two keys?
I am interested in using 'loc' as a single (sorted) variable

```
dt = data.table( 
  loc.x = as.integer(c(1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1)),
  loc.y = as.integer(c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)),
  value = letters[1:6]
)
setkey(dt, loc.x, loc.y)
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: mtoto, is there something like Python's tuple? I don't even know how to represent a pair object in R

Comment: I'm not sure, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't want to have two columns named 'loc.x' and 'loc.y'.
I want to have a single column named 'loc'. Each entry in 'loc' should be a pair of integers. The table should be sorted lexicographically by this 'loc' variable.

Comment: Why do you want them in a single column? What are you going to do next?

Comment: I need it just for readability. I use 'loc.x' and 'loc.y' dozens of times in the project. always together, never alone. 
Besides, I was wondering many times how to use "pair", or Python's "tuple", in R. This must be one of the most useful data structures natives (a point on geographical map, pixel location etc.)

Comment: @Amitai there is no native tuple. There are packages that have a tuple in them, but most functions will just take two values (often in matrix form), so you'll be better off keeping them separate until you need to display them. When you do, just combine into a new character column however you like, e.g. `dt[, loc := paste(loc.x, loc.y)]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive what you want but you could collapse them as characters and sort them which would give 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ..., 2.1, 2.2, ...

```
> loc.x = as.integer(c(1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1))
> loc.y = as.integer(c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2))
> x = cbind(loc.x,loc.y)
> sort(apply(x, 1, function(a) paste0(as.character(a), collapse = ".")))
[1] "1.1" "1.2" "1.2" "1.2" "3.1" "3.1"
```